# Select Dataframe columns by unpacking a collection of columns in conjunction with another collection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a piece of code where i am using unpacking of column names from a collection(called my_list) with certain condition( using map function) like this :

```
 val df1 = Seq(
  ("id1", "test_name1", "test_address1", "test_code1", "V1"),
  ("id2", "test_name2", "test_address2", "test_code2", "V2")
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d", "col_e")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("id1", "test_name1.1", "test_address1.1", "test_code1.1", "V1"),
  ("id4", "test_name4", "test_address4", "test_code4", "V4")
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d", "col_e")

val my_list = List("col_a", "col_b")
val my_list2 = List("col_c", "col_d", "col_e")
val joinDF = df1.as("l").join(df2.as("r"), df1("col_a") === df2("col_a"), "leftouter").select(col("l.col_c") :: col("l.col_d") :: col("l.col_e") :: my_list.map(my_function): _*)
```

}

my_function looks like :

```
def my_function(columnName: String) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
when(
  $"l.$columnName" === $"r.$columnName", null
).otherwise($"l.$columnName").as(columnName)
}
```

how to achieve unpacking another list(which is my_list2) in joinDF to avoid hardcoding set of column names(l.col_c, l.col_d, l.col_e), in conjunction with existing `my_list.map(my_function): _*` ?

I am seeing problem with unpacking second collection due to how variable arguments work.

Expected output:

```
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
|col_c        |col_d     |col_e|col_a|col_b     |
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
|test_address1|test_code1|V1   |null |test_name1|
|test_address2|test_code2|V2   |id2  |test_name2|
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: can you post full code ? & what is the output of my_function & what errors are you getting ?

Comment: @Srinivas added full code above.

Comment: can you also post your expected output ??

Comment: posted expected above.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you are expecting ?

```
scala>  df1.as("l").join(df2.as("r"), df1("col_a") === df2("col_a"), "leftouter").select((my_list2 ++ my_list).map(my_function): _*).show
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
|        col_c|     col_d|col_e|col_a|     col_b|
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
|test_address1|test_code1| null| null|test_name1|
|test_address2|test_code2|   V2|  id2|test_name2|
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: No. I don't want my_list2 items sent to my_function. main question is being able to unpack two collections/lists during select statement. One list unpack which is trivial, other list unpack run against my_function.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit conversion of SparkSession should be imported in the my_function:

```scala
def my_function(columnName: String) : org.apache.spark.sql.Column = {
  val spark = SparkConfig.getSparkSession
  import spark.implicits._
  when(
    $"l.$columnName" === $"r.$columnName", null
  ).otherwise($"l.$columnName").as(columnName)
}
```

SparkConfig:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SparkConfig {
  val APP_NAME: String = "app_name"
  var sparkConf: SparkConf = _
  var sparkSession: SparkSession = _


  def getSparkConf: SparkConf = {
    if(sparkConf == null) {
      val appName: String = APP_NAME
      sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName)
      sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")
    }
    sparkConf
  }


  def getSparkSession: SparkSession = {
    if(sparkSession == null)
      sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().config(getSparkConf).getOrCreate()
    sparkSession
  }
}
```

The following code has not been modified:

```scala
val spark = SparkConfig.getSparkSession
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(
  ("id1", "test_name1", "test_address1", "test_code1", "V1"),
  ("id2", "test_name2", "test_address2", "test_code2", "V2")
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d", "col_e")

val df2 = Seq(
  ("id1", "test_name1.1", "test_address1.1", "test_code1.1", "V1"),
  ("id4", "test_name4", "test_address4", "test_code4", "V4")
).toDF("col_a", "col_b", "col_c", "col_d", "col_e")

val my_list = List("col_a", "col_b")
val my_list2 = List("col_c", "col_d", "col_e")
val joinDF = df1.as("l")
  .join(df2.as("r"), df1("col_a") === df2("col_a"), "leftouter")
  .select(col("l.col_c") :: col("l.col_d") :: col("l.col_e") :: my_list.map(my_function): _*)
  .show()
```

output:

```
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
|        col_c|     col_d|col_e|col_a|     col_b|
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
|test_address1|test_code1|   V1| null|test_name1|
|test_address2|test_code2|   V2|  id2|test_name2|
+-------------+----------+-----+-----+----------+
```